# Prevent appending same data on ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5.4

My Ajax Call

```
$('#submitForm').click(function(){
var name = $('#agentOrCustomer').val();
var city = $('#city').val();
var enquiryType = $('#enquiryType').val();
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: '/search',
    data: {
        '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
        'name': $('input[name=name]').val(),
        'age'           : name,
        'city'          : city,
        'enquiryType'   : enquiryType
    },
    success: function(data) {
         $.each(data, function(index) {
            $('#table').append("<tr><td>"+data[index].id+"</td><td>"+data[index].first_name+"</td></tr>");

         });
    },
});
```

I'm currently working on searching users according their details. When I click on the search button the data will append and again the same data will append. How can I preventing getting the same data again and again?

Comment: You can discard the existing data

Comment: Assign ID to each `tr` and before appending, check if that ID exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can discard the existing data. Use [`.empty()`](https://api.jquery.com/empty/)/[`.html('')`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) to remove the content of table.

```
 $('#table').empty();
 $.each(data, function(index) {
    $('#table').append("<tr><td>"+data[index].id+"</td><td>"+data[index].first_name+"</td></tr>");
 });
```

---

Create a string and then use `.html()`

```
 var str = "";   
 $.each(data, function(index) {
    str += "<tr><td>"+data[index].id+"</td><td>"+data[index].first_name+"</td></tr>";
 });
 $('#table').html(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can empty the html of table:

```
$('#submitForm').click(function(){
 $('#table').html(""); // like this

var name = $('#agentOrCustomer').val();
var city = $('#city').val();
var enquiryType = $('#enquiryType').val();
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: '/search',
    data: {
        '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
        'name': $('input[name=name]').val(),
        'age'           : name,
        'city'          : city,
        'enquiryType'   : enquiryType
    },
    success: function(data) {
         $.each(data, function(index) {
            $('#table').append("<tr><td>"+data[index].id+"</td><td>"+data[index].first_name+"</td></tr>");

         });
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can check by assigning an ID. In the code, check if the `ID` already exists, if yes don't do anything, else append:

```
$.each(data, function(index) {
  if ($("#table tr#" + data[index].id).length) {
    // already exists... 
  } else {
    $('#table').append("<tr id=" + data[index].id + "><td>" + data[index].id + "</td><td>" + data[index].first_name + "</td></tr>");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add an id to the table row and then check if it exists or not:

```
success: function (data) {
    $.each(data, function (index) {
        var id = data[index].id;

        if (!$("#search-" + id).length) {
            $('#table').append("<tr id='search-" + id + "'><td>" + id + "</td><td>" + data[index].first_name + "</td></tr>");
        }


    });
},
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much @Ross Wilson